# How to update binding for async model change of shared service property for several controllers in AngularJS[?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a service for sharing a model between several controllers. This model is updated asynchronously (in a callback from a plugin). I'm running into issues where updating the model isn't updating the binding on several of the controller/view pairs. The only way I can think of to make this work is have each controller pass the service a callback function containing $scope.$apply. Each callback would then be run whenever the model is updated. This seems really messy to me. Is there a better approach?

Here's my sample snippet with just 1 controller. The important thing to remember is after the change is triggered, you navigate to a different page which uses a different controller sharing the service (so there's not controller event being called to update the $scope):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', ['myServ', function(myServ) {
 var controller = this;
 
 controller.myObject = myServ.myObject;
 
 controller.onChnge = function() {
  myServ.makeChange();
 };
 
}])

.factory('myServ', [function () {
 // Definitions ==============================
 var service = {};
 service.myObject = { value1: 25 };
 
 service.makeChange = function() {
  if (service.myObject.value1 === 25)
   setTimeout(function() { 
    service.myObject.value1 = 10;
   }, 1000);
  else
   setTimeout(function() { 
    service.myObject.value1 = 25;
   }, 1000);
 }
 
 return service;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
  Value: {{ ctrl.myObject.value1 }}<br>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.onChange()">Make Change</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: clarified source of asynchronous model change. Removed some un-needed code bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best solution, but I've used $watch to do this.

```
$scope.UserService = UserService;
$scope.$watch('UserService.getCurrentUser()', function (newVal) {
    $scope.currentUser = newVal;
}, true);
```

**EDIT**

Using angular's $timeout instead of setTimeout should take care of calling apply() to keep on top of all the asynchronous stuff.
https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout

Comment: I actually tried a $watch but they're only looked at when the digest is processed. Since my model is being updated asynchronously, the digest isn't triggered so the $watch doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, good one.... you could use angulars $timeout instead of setTimeout. $timeout will call an apply() for you.

https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout

Comment: Arg, I thought you had it! The problem is that my data isn't updated with a timeout, it's updated by a callback from a Bluetooth plugin. I'm trying to figure out a way to use it but no luck so far.

Comment: As it turns out the issue was in how I was updating the model, not in the binding at all. I'm going to set your answer as the correct one as it answers the question I posted.